# Expiring search highlights in Evil

Tags: evil, search, highlighting

I'm using the `evil-search` module (`(evil-select-search-module 'evil-search-module 'evil-search)`). When I perform a search, the results remain highlighted until I call `evil-ex-nohighlight`.

I'd prefer that the highlights go away by themselves after a few seconds. I tried `(setq evil-ex-search-persistent-highlight nil)`, but this setting apparently doesn't apply to `evil-search`. Is there a way of having auto-expiring highlights with `evil-search`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `(setq evil-ex-search-persistent-highlight nil)` and `(evil-select-search-module 'evil-search-module 'evil-search)` searching for matches with `/` highlights them while I enter the pattern, then removes the highlight after pressing `RET` or aborting the search.  This is the full extent of `evil-ex-search-persistent-highlight`, it does not apply to commands such as `n` and `N`.  Patches welcome for these.